# Does Google Cloud Storage uploading trigger a Firebase Cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I need to upload files to Firebase Cloud Storage with REST api; I read that Firebase doesn't provide them but Google Cloud Storage does. I need that a firebase cloud function will be triggered on uploads. I know that Firebase is backed by GCS, so I'll use it, but I didn't find if upload on GCS will trigger a Firebase Cloud function too. Does anybody know anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody answered me, I tried and the result is: **yes**, Firebase function is triggered even if I use GCS rest api to upload on bucket.

Comment: Any changes to your project storage bucket will trigger a storage function in that project.  It doesn't matter where the change comes from.